# How a Summation enables Permutation?

Tags: summation, permutations

I am reading an [article](https://www.arxiv-vanity.com/papers/1903.07745/) of creating an embedding which is order-invariant to inputs ($m_{l}$). They refered to order-invariance in eq (5) as follows:

> The order-invariant operation happens in (5), where permuting $m_l$
> with $m_{′l}$ yields the same vector $r_t$ , due to the summation.

First what exactly is $m_{′l}$? is it transpose of  $m_l$? Second, how is permutation happening?

$$r_t=\sum\nolimits_{l=1}^{L_i}a_{l,t}m_l$$
here, $m_l$ points to $l^{th}$ vector and $a_{l,t}$ is merely some scalar weight. and $r_t$ is the vector returned.